# How to apply keepalive when sending push using firebase-admin

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I use firebase-admin java sdk (version : 6.8.0)

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(resource.getInputStream()))
     .setFirestoreOptions(firestoreOptions)
     .setDatabaseUrl(firebaseDatabaseUrl)
     .setConnectTimeout(3000)
     .setReadTimeout(5000)
     .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

I am sending android push using the code above.

However, if you send 10 pushes, it will connect and disconnect 10 times.

How do I apply keepalive?

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about what you're observing, and how that's different than what you expect.  What you have right now is too vague.

Comment: Isn't there a connection pool?

Comment: There might be, but you could be doing something that's working against any sort of optimizations the SDK might have.  We can't tell until we know exactly how you are running this code and what you're observing.  Please edit the question to be more specific about what you're doing and how you're observing behavior that's different than what you expect.

Comment: If you want to know about the inner workings of the Firebase Admin SDK, you can always go directly to the source code: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java

Comment: I think you're affected by https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/issues/367 (see my last comment in that issue). I can see how that can affect some Firebase API clients.